# не знаю как собрать программу с помощью Makefile

Tags: linux, c, gcc, makefile

Решил собрать простейший пример через `Makefile` , для понимания процесса .

Собирать по простому я могу `gcc test.c -o tream` , а проекты собираю в IDE QtCreator-e по сему не когда напрямую с `Makefile` не работал.

Но вот решил собрать с помощью только Makefil-а который я самодельно написал ,
НО у вы почему-то выводит ошибку :(

```
 comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ gcc Makefile text.c
/usr/bin/ld:Makefile: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:Makefile:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ gcc Makefile 
/usr/bin/ld:Makefile: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:Makefile:3: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Вот "код"   Makefile :

```
CC = c11

all : test

test : test.o
        gcc -o test test.o 

test.o : test.c
        gcc -c test.c

clean :
        rm test *.o
```

Вот "код"   test.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    printf("2212121212");
    return 0;
}
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Так а зачем вы компилятору-то подсовываете make файл. Его надо подавать на вход утилите make.

Comment: просто дай команду `make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Fat-zer

вот удалось , правда пришлось слегка поправить `Makefile` в  местах после перевода строки были пробелы :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ ls
Makefile  test.c  tream
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ make
Makefile:6: *** пропущен разделитель (возможно нужен TAB вместо восьми пробелов?).  Останов.
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ make
gcc -c test.c
gcc -o test test.o 
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ ls
Makefile  test  test.c  test.o  tream
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$ ./test 
2212121212comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/initial_kusok/test$
```

вот код `Makefile`:

```
# стандарт по-умолчанию вашего проекта
CS = c11
# имя компилятора
CC = gcc

all : test

test : test.o
    $(CC) -o test test.o 

test.o : test.c
    $(CC) -c -std=$(CS) test.c

clean :
    rm test *.o
```

Comment: строка "CC = c11" не делает ничего.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev почему ??

Comment: Потому что не используется нигде.

Comment: Про `make`, как и про любую другую программу, кстати, книги написаны. Рекомендую: Managing Projects with GNU Make издательства O'Reilly.

Comment: чтобы использовать `c11` , нужно в  компилятор прописать опцию : `gcc -c -std=$(CC) test.c`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Извините я как то не понял как это сделать , можете пожалуйста изменить мой `Makefile` что бы опция находилась в нужном месте , а то у меня так и не вышло